# Is it necessarily so that you can POST a byte stream to any API that will accept a file, or does it depend on the API?

Tags: java, rest, apache-commons-httpclient

I have come to the understanding that knowing this is indicative of a lack of knowledge of how REST-like APIs work, and if someone can provide me a reference where I can learn the background behind this question, I would appreciate it.  In the meantime, though, I would also appreciate help answering this question!

I have a java application that posts files from the local filesystem to an API.  My goal is to instead of having millions of files sitting on the volume with all of their file handles, I want to leave the files in a .tar.gz file, and then in memory pull them out of archive and POST them without writing them to disk.  I know that I can write them to disk, POST them, and then delete them, but I view that option as a last resort.

So here's code that works to POST a file that exists in the file system, not in an archive

```
public CloseableHttpResponse submit (File file) throws IOException {
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(API_LOCATION + API_BASE);
    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.addBinaryBody("files", file, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, null);
    HttpEntity multipartEntity = builder.build();
    post.setEntity(multipartEntity);

    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    System.out.println("response: " + IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent(),"UTF-8"));
    client.close();
    return response;
}
```

I get back a JSON response from my particular API that looks like this

```
response: {"data":[<bunch of json>]}
```

I've put the same file into a .tar.gz archive and have used apache commons compress to unzip the file and pull out each file as a TarArchiveEntry, and I've tested that it works properly by writing the text file to disk and opening it manually outside of java - I am definitely getting the entry into memory correctly.  I tried changing the entity attached to the POST to a ByteArrayEntity and converting the archive entry to a byte stream, but the API insists it will only accept a multipart entity.  So looking at the API for MultipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody it appears I'm left with two options:  I can either post a byte array or an InputStream.  I've tried both and I can't get either to work - I'll post my example code for the byte array approach, but I can't figure out how to convert the tar archive to an InputStream - at least not without converting it to a byte array first, which seems sorta silly at that point.

```
public CloseableHttpResponse submit (byte[] xmlBytes) throws IOException {
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(API_LOCATION + API_BASE);
    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.addBinaryBody("files", xmlBytes, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, null);
    HttpEntity multipartEntity = builder.build();
    post.setEntity(multipartEntity);

    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    System.out.println("response: " + IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent(),"UTF-8"));
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    client.close();
    return response;
}
```

I believe the code is identical with the exception of the data type of the input parameter.  Here is my empty response, which comes with a status code 207:

```
response: {"data":[]}
```

So here is my real question:  Can any API that accept files also accept a file in the form of a byte stream or byte array?  Can the API tell the difference, and what is really happening when I POST a file?  Does the API have to be specifically configured to accept this file in the form of a byte stream or a byte array?  A link to a reference along with a short explanation would be highly appreciated - I really need to learn this stuff and understand it well.

Is there some easy to correct mistake that I'm making?  Am I using the wrong Content-Type or something?  I'm not even sure what the meaning of the third argument to MultipartEntityBuilder.build is (the one I've left null).

Any help is appreciated, thank you very much!

Comment: You're passing null as the file name. When passing a File as argument, the actual name of the File is used if you passed null as file name. That doesn't happen obviously if you pass a bute array. So specify a non-null file name as last argument. That can only be found out by reading the javadoc and the source code of MultipartEntityBuilder. It's open source: use that as an advantage.

Comment: When I add a random file name instead of null, I get the following response:

{"data":[{"meta":{"filename":"someFile.xml","error":{"status":400,"title":"Load request failed due to malformed XML.","detail":"SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in trailing section."}}}]}

It looks like something about that string is getting appended to the file itself, somehow?

Comment: Adding a file name fixed the problem, as JB Nizet said.  The extra content was a mistake I made when converting to a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that an API that accepts a file doesn't care if it comes from a file object or a byte array.  Per JB Nizet:

> You're passing null as the file name. When passing a File as argument, the actual name of the File is used if you passed null as file name. That doesn't happen obviously if you pass a bute array. So specify a non-null file name as last argument. That can only be found out by reading the javadoc and the source code of MultipartEntityBuilder. It's open source: use that as an advantage.

In this specific case, adding a random string as the last argument of the build method fixes the problem and the API accepts the byte array as a file.